# SQL Sever 2008 R2 report integrate into ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, reporting-services

I have created some lovely reports using "SQL Server Business Intelligence Development" creating a "report Server Project". I have deployed these to SQL Server reporting services and viewed online and they look great!

Question is...can I integrate these reports into my ASP.NET webforms site? So for example I could pass in values to my stored procedure and the port is generated using the same reports created previously mentioned.

Is this possible? If so, please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to integrate serving reports into your website is to use the ASP.NET ReportViewer control. I've not used this myself, but is is straight forward and just requires that the reports are deployed to an accessible report server (which you have already done).

You can also formulate your own url to create a direct link to a PDF version of the report as follows:

```
http://localhost/ReportServer?MyReportName&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&MyParamter=MyVal
```

Finally, you can use a page or handler as an intermediary by call the Report Server's web service and processing the result (possible simply by Response.BinaryWrite(result).